# Add a custom regex validation in jQuery Validation Engine

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, jquery-validation-engine

I have problems adding a custom validation to validate fields entering time (with [jQuery Validation Engine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/)), in the following manner: hh:mm (e.g. 12:30);

As far as I know I should add the following

```
"timeFormat":{ 
    "regex":"/^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/",
    "alertText":" errormessage in the locale chosen"}                           
}
```

in `jquery.validationEngine-(the locale).js`

and add the following in the input field `class="validate[custom[timeFormat]]"`

But for some reason it doesn't work, whatever I've entered it displays that the field is not valid. I suspect that my regex is something wrong, but I've tested it in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and it seems pretty OK.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the quotes around your regex. Try this here:

```
"timeFormat":{
    "regex": /^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/,
    "alertText":" errormessage in the locale chosen"                           
}
```